# NSOutlineView expand items by default with `autosaveExpandedItems`

Tags: appkit, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView that uses `autosaveExpandedItems` to remember which items are in an expanded state and which are collapsed, this is working well.

The other requirement I have is that all items should be expanded by default, unless the user has collapsed it. At the moment, all new items are collapsed by default.

Is there any way to achieve this?

edit:

Let's assume 5 (could be any number) static groups, on first load I can `expandAll` which expands all 5. If I collapse 2 and close the window the next time I open it all will be expanded again due to the `expandAll` call, instead of remembering that 2 were collapsed. Taking out the `expandAll` call will properly save the expand/collapse states, but it then defaults all to collapsed. So on first open all will be collapsed, instead of expanded.

Comment: What is preventing you from expanding the items?

Comment: If I do something like `outlineView.expandAllItems()` they will all expand, but will also blow away any state a user might have saved where they collapsed an item.

Comment: Which items whould be expanded when? How and when are items added?

Comment: Lets assume 5 groups, on first load I can `expandAll` which expands all 5. If I collapse 2 and close the window the next time I open it all will be expanded again due to the `expandAll` call, instead of remembering that 2 were collapsed. Taking out the call `expandAll` call will properly save the expand/collapse states, but it defaults all to collapsed. So on first open all will be collapsed, instead of expanded.

Comment: Hi there, have you found any solutions regarding this problem? I have a similar case in which I need to expand items by default. Using `outlineView.expandItem` would cause unwanted animation.

Comment: @francisfeng I had to disable the built in state restoration and roll my own to work the way that I wanted it to unfortunately.